# Perl - Change messagebox title bar icon

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

How to change icon present in the title bar of message box using perl tk?

Comment: Which platform? (The code is wildly different under the covers depending on whether this is for Unix, Windows or OSX.)

Comment: @Donal Platform is windows. I am using activestate perl also till now I am using Perl/TK not any win32 modules

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you change the icon for message boxes (and other system dialogs) by changing the [default window icon](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M36). Alas, I can't find out how to write that in Perl, as I find [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.029/pod/Wm.pod#DESCRIPTION) confusing. (I know what I'd write in Tcl; it needs the `-default` option enabled…)